# Java: Port not available (on Windows 7)

Tags: java, sockets, port

**Solved:** 
The problem was a "virus" or something similar that was hijacking the port.
OBS: The virus hijacked the por in a way the port didn't appear on netstat -an or TCPView of ports being used.

I used the AVG antivirus to remove the virus.
Another antivirus didn't work, just AVG.

---

I did this program to check if a port is available:

```
package com.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.ServerSocket;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Port available: " + available(62974));
    }
    public static boolean available(int port) {
        ServerSocket ss = null;
    try {
        ss = new ServerSocket(port);
        ss.setReuseAddress(true);
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (ss != null) {
            try {
                ss.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
    }
}
```

The response is **false**.

The exception thrown is:

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:383)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:328)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:194)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:106)
    at com.dgs.test.Test.available(Test.java:16)
    at com.dgs.test.Test.main(Test.java:9)
```

I'm using this port: 62974

But I check on Console/prompt-dos with:

```
netstat -ano
```

The port **is not on the list**.

**I'm not using any firewall, I deactivated it**

Am I doing the right thing to see if the port is available?

Is this a "not usable" port?

Comment: If `false` is returned an `IOException` was thrown (and was caught) because that's the only way to get to the `return false`.

Comment: I can confirm that port 62974 is usable on Windows 7 for both TCP and UDP sockets. Why do you need this port in particular?

Comment: The reddwarfserver lib (http://reddwarfserver.org) uses it. The Reddwarf just stop working giving the same exception of my example program.

Comment: For the record, I ran your code verbatim and it always returns `true` for me.  There's something else wrong on your system.  Have you tried rebooting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code should try to become a client rather than a server when testing an active TCP/UDP port either locally or remotely.

```
package com.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

public class PortScan {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length > 0 ){
            System.out.println("Port active: " + available(args[0], args[1]));
        }
        else System.out.println("Usage: PortScan <ip> <port>");
    }

    public static boolean available(String ip, String port) {
        boolean status = false;
        Socket ss = null;
        try {
            ss = new Socket(ip, Integer.parseInt(port));
            status = true; //there is a listening port 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (ss != null) {
                try {
                    ss.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        return status;
    }
}
```

Take this current nestat -ano result:

```
  TCP    192.168.72.1:139       0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    192.168.184.1:139      0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  UDP    0.0.0.0:445            *:*                                    4
```

When there is already a UDP service is active but it is not listening at 127.0.0.1:445 or a TCP service is active and it is listening at 192.168.184.1:139, when you test `PortScan 127.0.0.1 445` or `PortScan 192.168.184.1 139`, it will connect and say "Port active: true":

When there is no service at a given port (probably not active or blocked); let say "127.0.0.1:446", it will catch a "Connection refused" and say "Port active: false":

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.PortScan.available(PortScan.java:18)
    at com.test.PortScan.main(PortScan.java:9)
Port active: false
```

However, you will need to check why it is refusing; is it really not active or is it being blocked by a firewall? It is a tricky problem that you need to find out.

After that, you can code to become a server and try to establish itself on a free/inactive port, like below:

```
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(port));
            serverSocket.setReceiveBufferSize(2048);
            serverSocket.setSoTimeout(0);
            serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
        } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        //do something here in a loop

        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**Update:**

Make sure the previous run (that involves the server code part) is closed properly in Eclipse when you are trying to connect again with another run. Check **Debug view** of Eclipse and close the offending previous run before testing. Otherwise, you will get a `BindException` when trying to establish a server code on the same port which is already active.

To check whether the server port has been established, use:

```
netstat -ano | find "62974"
```

Comment: I deactivated the firewall. You're right, the "Connection Refuse" was thrown on port 62974.
I also used TCPView to check if the port is available it isn't. Couldn't it be a eclipse launching issue?

Comment: It is probably that the previous run is not closed properly when you are trying to connect again with another run. Check Debug view of Eclipse and close the offending previous run.

Comment: It isn't this. It would be very silly of my part. But we must check all possibilities.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are attempting to open the port for listening twice.  Serversocket accepts TCP connections while DatagramSocket accepts UDP datagrams.  You cannot open the same port twice.  This explains the binding IO exception you are getting.

Comment: TCP and UDP "port spaces" are disjoint, and you can use the same port for both simultaneously.

Comment: Thron, I changed the program:
Now the program just open a ServerSocket. The exception is the same ad is thrown when it reaches the line: "new ServerSocket(port);
Thanks.

Comment: reboot your pc and try again.

Comment: I already tried this.
I think the question is: what is on 62974 that is hidden on netstat -ano. Just one anser: It's a virus!? I already passed AVG antivirus and SuperAntispyware, I did remove the "normal" malwares (and uninstalled these softwares to make sure it's not blocking any port). After all I reset the PC to make sure any port is been blocked.
But when I restart and run the test above it says the port is blocked...

Comment: try running wireshark to view all the ip traffic on your pc. http://www.wireshark.org/